# Is there any way to keep the data from a view in sqlserver is always right?

Tags: sql-server

This problem happened at a SQL Server Express 2019, my SQL script is not much special which with another view in it and did a left outer join connection.

In my situation, the SQL script, there's one record was returned, and one of its field names "DeleteFlag" returns 0 when not in the view, but it changed when put into the view be the content of it, just returns 1!

It's so weird that I tried times to find out the discrepancy, but no result. And in the process, the situation is stably reproducing.

The problem disappeared after I operated the auto generated alter view script to refresh it. But when I restored the backup database, It reproduced then. every time I restore the DB backup, it reproduced!

Reproduce steps and related files:

1. Unpack and restore the `*.bak` file ([test111.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GatLvSE8G4-gOXA2DwwEBei2WTtvhZNo/view?usp=sharing)), you'll get a database named "ADS_STARTUP_DB_2401"
2. Do a selection on the view `[medDispense].[PatientProfile]`, you'll get one row and the column names `DeleteFlag`, the value is 1:

   ```
    SELECT DeleteFlag 
    FROM [medDispense].[PatientProfile]
   ```
3. Then go to the definition of `[medDispense].[PatientProfile]`:

   ```
    CREATE VIEW [medDispense].[PatientProfile] 
    AS
        SELECT DISTINCT
            inventory.StationID, patientProfile.* 
        FROM 
            V_PATIENT_PROFILE patientProfile 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            V_INVENTORY inventory ON patientProfile.Billnum = inventory.Billnum 
        WHERE 
            (patientProfile.Active = 1) 
            AND (patientProfile.DeleteFlag = 0) 
            AND (inventory.DeleteFlag IS NULL OR inventory.DeleteFlag = 0)
   ```

   Then, operating the bold part statement, you'll see one record and look at the column `DeleteFlag`, you'll see the value is 0. The issue is just here.

So, I'm thinking if this problem happened one day at the users' program which is connecting a SQL Server 2019 Express. The data result was definitely wrong, but there's no fault to any developer. It would be so weird.

So is there a way to keep the data from a view is always right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server View showing outdated / wrong data after changing underlying dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373093/sql-server-view-showing-outdated-wrong-data-after-changing-underlying-dependen)

Comment: Develop good habits. Define short but not cryptic aliases for each table and use them for every column reference. Use 2 part names to reference tables (e.g, dbo.V_PATIENT_PROFILE). And I question the need for using DISTINCT. Often it a kludge to solve a logic problem in the query. And lastly - encourage others to look at your issue by formatting your code to make it more readable. The more scrolling I have to do, the less interested I am in helping. Maybe that's just me. But it is a good habit to write readable code.

Comment: Hi, Charlieface, thanks for your reply.

Comment: At the similar question content, I only get that "sp_refreshview view_name" can also resolve the issue, which is similar to operating the alter script for a view, and that's all.
But, what I want to know is how to keep the function right without operating a alter script or sp_refreshview.
Our program is changing, software versions will be upgrade, thus some modifications on views can be avoided. It is not easy to ensure every view change will not cause this issue.

Comment: It seems a issue that no databases has been resolved.

Comment: Also thanks for the advice come from SMor,  And the code was written long time ago, and it will be optimized if get chance.